# Cambiar color de un DIV con PHP

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

Buenas, tengo un `div` en Bootstrap de color azul y un código `PHP`. Me gustaría que se cambiase el color del `div` automáticamente a rojo si el contenido es inferior a `95`.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class='<?php echo ($registros <95)? panel panel-red: panel panel-blue;?>'>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <i class="fa fa-percent fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="font-size:55px;">
                                 <?php
         $sql = "SELECT ANSMensual1 FROM cauctti.datosglobales where Ambito like 'SSU Intern'";
         $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
         while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        ?>
            <?php echo $registros["ANSMensual1"] ?>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="detallmensual.php">
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <span class="pull-left">ANS MENSUAL SSU Intern</span>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Esto debería dar error/aviso en PHP porque faltan comillas en varios sitios.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estás usando mal la condición. Debería ser algo así:

```
<div <?php if ($registros <95) { echo 'class="panel panel-red"'; } else { echo 'class="panel panel-blue"'; } ?>>
```

En todo caso, si quieres utilizar el operador ternario, podrías hacerlo así:

```
<div class="<?php echo $registros < 95 ? 'panel panel-red' : 'panel panel-blue'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Así debe funcionar, noto que tiene un error:

1. Debes haber obtenido el valor de registro por (ámbito) antes de
   verificar su valor para asignar la clase CSS que corresponde.
2. Lo que devuelve la consulta es un arreglo (array):

   `while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

   ... y deberías usar `count($result) > 95`.

Queda de esta manera:

```
<div class="<?php echo ($registros < 95)?'panel panel-red':'panel panel-blue';?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
<div class='<?php ($registros <95)? echo 'panel panel-red': echo 'panel panel-blue';?>'>
```

el punto es que la formulación está errónea, recuerda que un script de PHP de ejecuta de 'arriba hacia abajo' y tu campo `$registro` lo defines *después* en tu consulta SQL, es decir, aún no existe cuando lo llamas en un ternario de arriba.

Te recomiendo hacer algo así (no revisé el script y puede tener errores, pero para que entiendas la idea)

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT ANSMensual1 FROM cauctti.datosglobales where Ambito like 'SSU Intern'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

$registroGuardado = 0;
$registros = 0;

while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $registroGuardado = $registros["ANSMensual1"];
}

?>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class='<?php ($registros < 95)? echo 'panel panel-red'; : echo 'panel panel-blue';?>'>
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-percent fa-5x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="font-size:55px;">
                     <?php echo $registroGuardado; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="detallmensual.php">
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <span class="pull-left">ANS MENSUAL SSU Intern</span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

saludos